# Blending V.S. offscreen-rendering, which is worse for Core Animation performance?

Tags: ios, core-animation

Blending and offscreen-rendering are both expensive in Core Animation.

One can see them in Core Animation instrument in Instruments, with Debug Options:
[image: Instruments]

Here is my case:

Display 50x50 PNG images on UIImageViews. I want to round the images with a 6-point corer radius. The first method is to set UIImageView.layer's cornerRadius and masksToBounds which causes offscreen-rendering. The second method is to make PNG image copies with transparent corners which causes blending(because of the alpha channel).

I've tried both, but I can't see significant performance difference. However, I still want to know which is worse in theory and best practices if any.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

Well, short answer, the blending has to occur either way to correctly display the transparent corner pixels.  However, this should typically only be an issue if you want the resulting view to also animate in some way (and remember, scrolling is the most common type of animation). Also, I'm able to recreate situations where "cornerRadius" will cause rendering errors on older devices (iPhone 3G in my case) when my views become complex. For situations where you do need performant animations, here are the recommendations I follow.

First, if you only need the resources with a single curve for the rounded corners (different scales are fine, as long as the desired curvature is the same), save them that way to avoid the extra calculation of "cornerRadius" at runtime.

Second, don't use transparency anywhere you don't need it (e.g. when the background is actually a solid color), and always specify the correct value for the "opaque" property to help the system more efficiently calculate the drawing.

Third, find ways to minimize the size of transparent views.  For example, for a large border view with transparent elements (e.g. rounded corners), consider splitting the view into 3 (top, middle, bottom) or 7 (4 corners, top middle, middle, bottom middle) parts, keeping the transparent portions as small as possible and marking the rectangular portions as opaque, with solid backgrounds.

Fourth, in situations where you're drawing lots of text in scrollViews (e.g. highly customized UITableViewCell), consider using the "drawRect:" method to render these portions more efficiently. Continue using subviews for image elements, in order to split the render time between the overall view between pre-drawing (subviews) and "just-in-time" drawing (drawRect:).  Obviously, experimentation (frames per second while scrolling) could show that violating this "rule-of-thumb" may be optimal for your particular views.

Finally, making sure you have plenty of time to experiment using the profiling tools (especially CoreAnimation) is key.  I find that it's easiest to see improvements using the slowest device you want to target, and the results look great on newer devices.

Answer (score 6):

After watching WWDC videos and having some experiments with Xcode and Instruments I can say that blending is better then offscreen rendering. Blending means that system requires some additional time to calculate color of pixels on transparent layers. The more transparent layers you have (and bigger size of these layers) then blending takes more time.

Offscreen rendering means that system will make more then one rendering iteration. At first iteration system will make rendering without visualization just to calculate bounds and shape of area which should be rendered. In next iterations system does regular rendering (depends on calculated shape) including blending if required.

Also for offscreen rendering system creates a separate graphics context and destroys it after rendering.

So you should avoid offscreen rendering and it's better to replace it with blending.